# How to uncompress zip file fast with Mathematica?

Tags: import, compression

**What is the fastest possibilty to uncompress zip files with the following content?**

It containes numbered ".png" files, corresponding ".header" files (theses are text files) and a file called "png_content.txt" (also a text file).

In reality a zip file has a size of about 3 GB, each png has a size of 1 MB, the header files are of about 600 Bytes and the "png_content.txt" is about 200 KB of size.

What I tried which fails:

```
dir = NotebookDirectory[];

SetDirectory[dir];

data = Import["file.zip"];

len = Length[data];

Do[
 element = Import["data.zip", data[[i]]];
 Export[data[[i]], element];
 Print[data[[i]]];
 , {i, 1, len}
 ]
```

I see that I have to extract the file type somehow and then provide the information that the ".header" files are text files.

As mentioned my zip files are relatively large. When I use winzip it takes on my computer about 1 min to uncompress a zip file of 3.3 GB (about 3300 png files, plus the other text files).

I have many of such zip files which I would uncompress one by one do something with the contained data, and continue with the next zip file.

Therefore I need a fast solution to uncompress a single zip file (with Mathematica).

Here is a small example zip file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PvzxC2HKcSCLFL01i2jtOcjrV2ziqyAD

Comment: You could multi-thread it or accept better hardware willl be cheaper, quicker and make the code easier to maintain: https://blog.codinghorror.com/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive/

Comment: @WolframFan WHAT??? You try to tell me that it would be cheaper to buy or rent a HPC cluster instead of investing 10 seconds to run gunzip from the command line?

Comment: @lio Apart from the fact that there is no point in zipping png files because they are already compressed: It might be a better idea to `Run` `gunzip` or a similar command line tool.

Comment: @Henrik I'm suggesting an SSD, in my experience throwing an SSD at Mathematica is a match made in heaven.

Comment: @lio I cannot tell how to do that on Windows, but on unixoid platforms, this should be possible with, e.g., `Import["!unzip -o /Users/Henrik/Downloads/file.zip", "Text"]`. The exclamation mark `!` means that the string following is sent to command line and executed there; the returned string is the output from the command line. You can use the option `-d` to specify an output directory.

Comment: @WolframFan The point here is that it is not necessary to loop all data through the Math Kernel. I have an SSD, still, the simple example given by OP took 48 seconds on my machine, while it takes 0.17 seconds to run it on command line (and the latter does it correctly). That's a speedup factor of 280, essentially for free!

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @lio You're welcome.

Comment: Why are you not using ExtractArchive? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExtractArchive.html